# Building dynamic lambda expression

Tags: dynamic, lambda, tree, expression, expression-trees

I know how to build a simple lambda like *x => x > 5*:

```
int[] nbs = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };            
IEnumerable<int> result1 = nbs.Where(x => x > 5);

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(5);
BinaryExpression expressionBody = Expression.GreaterThan(parameter, constant);
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(expressionBody, parameter);
IEnumerable<int> result2 = nbs.Where(expression.Compile());
```

But, how do I build a lambda like this *p => p.Cars.Any(c => c.Horsepowers > 300)*?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public int Horsepowers { get; set; }
}

Person p1 = new Person();
p1.Name = "Thom";
p1.Cars = new List<Car>()
{
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 100, Make = "Toyota"},
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 200, Make = "Fiat"},
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 300, Make = "Audi"},
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 400, Make = "Ferrari"}
};

Person p2 = new Person();
p2.Name = "Allen";
p2.Cars = new List<Car>()
{
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 500, Make = "McLaren"},
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 200, Make = "Volvo"},
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 300, Make = "Audi"},
 new Car(){Horsepowers = 400, Make = "Ferrari"}
};

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(p1);
persons.Add(p2);

IEnumerable<Person> res = persons.Where(p => p.Cars.Any(c => c.Horsepowers > 300));
```

In other words, how do I build an expression ( `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` ) dynamically that I can pass as a parameter to the Where method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a complex expression tree start from leaves and go up to the root. In your case you can start with building inner lambda `c => c.Horsepowers > 300`:

```
var c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Car), "c");
var horsepower = Expression.PropertyOrField(c, "Horsepowers");
var minHorsepower = Expression.Constant(300);
var grateThen = Expression.GreaterThan(horsepower, minHorsepower);
var innerLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Car, bool>>(grateThen, c);
```

Now you can create `p.Cars.Any(...)` and put your inner lambda inside

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p");
var cars = Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "Cars");
var any = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), 
    nameof(Enumerable.Any), 
    new[] {typeof(Car)}, 
    cars,
    innerLambda
  );
```

After that build your root lambda:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(any, p);
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that I had to pass cars as an argument as well to the Expression.Call-method! Feels a little bit strange that cars also should be an argument to the Any-method...

Comment: @AndyRehn it's because `Any` is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). You can write `Enumerable.Any(cars, c => ...)` or just `cars.Any(c => ...)`